# Spark Streaming - Kafka Integration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

We are using small spark cluster with 5 nodes and all these 5 nodes were connected with Kafka brokers.

We are planning to scale the cluster by adding more nodes and this may require configuring this additional to connect with the Kafka cluster .We are assessing the best practices of integrations

- How it actually to be integrated to make the integration as easy as possible
- Is it needed for all the workers node to be connected with the
  brokers , in that case , it might not be scalable ?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to go over the documentation of spark with kafka integretion

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

"How it actually to be integrated to make the integration as easy as possible" :

I'm not sure what do you mean - but basically when you connect to kafka you should provide the bootstrap servers : Bootstrap Servers are a list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.
These servers are just used for the initial connection to discover the full cluster membership. so the number of nodes of the kafka cluster will not change the way you integrate

"Is it needed for all the workers node to be connected with the brokers , in that case , it might not be scalable ?" :

spark integration works in the following way (sort of):

1. the sprak driver - connects to the kafka to understand the required partitions and offsets
2. based on part 1 the partitions are assigned to the spark "workers" - which is usually a 1 to 1 from a kafka partition to a spark partition.

- not all workers (I guess you mean executors) connect to all kafka nodes - so in this case it is also scalable

side note : you can use a configuration to further break the number of spark partitions that would read from a single kafka partition - its called minPartitions and its from spark 2.4.7

last note : spark streaming with kafka is a very used and known use case and is used in very big data ecosystems as a first intuitive thought I would assume its scalable

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs. How the integration works if all the workers _not_ connected to the bootstrap servers (via a single driver )? How integration looks like from spark side or kafka side? The article is very highlevel and I am looking for _real_ experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the following phrase while going though the book , https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/stream-processing-with/9781491944233/ch19.html

Particularly the phrase `The driver does not send data to the executors; instead, it simply sends a few offsets they use to directly consume data.` - seems the _all the executors( worker nodes) have to have connection with the kafka as it is quite possible the tasks might run on any executor

> The gist of data delivery is that the Spark driver queries offsets and
> decides offset ranges for every batch interval from Apache Kafka.
> After it receives those offsets, the driver dispatches them by
> launching a task for each partition, resulting in a 1:1 parallelism
> between the Kafka partitions and the Spark partitions at work. Each
> task retrieves data using its specific offset ranges.
>
> The driver does
> not send data to the executors; instead, it simply sends a few offsets
> they use to directly consume data. As a consequence, the parallelism
> of data ingestion from Apache Kafka is much better than the legacy
> receiver model, where each stream was consumed by a single machine.